Can sum of a geometric progression with n terms be derived using Binomial Expansion?
Let's say we have a GP: $a, ar, ar^2, .... , ar^n$, i.e.
$$a( 1 + r + r^2 + .... + r^n)$$
Can we deduce this sum using Binomial Theorem? Since $(1+r)^n$ can be opened up but with some unwanted terms?

What do you mean by "deduce this sum?"

To reach the same expression of a GP sum as we learn in high school but with this approach.

Then write out the full question. It is not even clear in the question if you know that formula.

Oh sorry, I thought people would already know that much.

We know that much, but we don't know what you know, and it is clear what you are asking without knowing what you know.

The sums are not related in any way except that they have the same powers. If you want a closed-form expression for the geometric series, it is
$$1 + r + \ldots + r^n = \frac{1 - r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
if $0 \le r < 1$.
The reason they are not related is that the coefficients of the geometric series are $g_i = 1$ while the coefficients of the binomial series are $b_i = \binom{n}{i}$ for $i \in \{0,\ldots,n\}$.
EDIT: to expand on this answer, we can show the value of the binomial series is insufficient to deduce the value of the geometric series. Consider $(r, n) = (0.5, 2)$ and $\left( \sqrt[3]{2.25}-1, 3 \right)$. The binomial series values are equal:
$$ (1 + 0.5)^2 = 2.25 = \left( 1 + \sqrt[3]{2.25}-1 \right)^3. $$
However, the geometric series values are not:
$$ \frac{1 - 0.5^{3}}{1-0.5} = 1.75 $$
$$ \frac{1 - 0.3104^{4}}{1-0.3104} \approx 1.4366, $$
where $\sqrt[3]{2.25}-1 \approx 0.3104.$
Now, if we know the value of the binomial series in addition to either $r$ or $n$, that is enough information to substitute into the geometric series expression to relate the two.

The closed form is correct. However I don't think the reason that you gave is valid. All we can say is that we don't know anything that connects the two so far.

I don't know why this question is downvoted, seems like a decent thinking exercise to me. The coefficients in the binomial expansion do come in the way and I couldn't find a way myself to do anything about them. I will try again.

@DuongNgo what we can say for certain is that simply knowing the value of the binomial sum tells you nothing about that geometric sum because there is not enough information (two variables, one known value). If you know the binomial sum as a function of r and n, a simple relation between the two is simply inserting r and n into the geometric series closed form (using whatever equations you can derive to isolate the two variables).
